# php pass parameter in url

Tags: php, html

I have a `form` and a PHP function:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['sub'])) {
  var_dump($_REQUEST);
  die;
}
?>

<form action="index.php?a=12" method="get">
  <input name="sub" type="submit" value="Calc">
</form>
```

But when I click to submit I get nothing.

How can I pass variable **a** in URL (without any inputs) and why this method doesn't work?

Comment: you would need to use a hidden input - if you are hard coding it though, why not just set a constant in your php then it will be less likely that someone can change the value of it

Comment: I know that i can use hidden input, but i try to pass it in url. Is it impossible?

Comment: Because you're using `get` as the form method - the inputs from the form override the URL parameters in the `action` - it works if you `post` the form.

Comment: So if I want to pass someting in url I must use post method? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to append additional parameters to the URL in `action` yes... there aren't many situations where you'd actually want to do this though - normally you'd use POST if you're updating a resource and GET if you're retrieving one; rarely both together which is what you'd be doing, technically.

Answer (score 0):

You need **a**, but you get **sub**. It's problem. And you must use **a** for **input**. You can see difference in this code.

```html
<?php
if(isset($_GET['a'])) {
var_dump($_REQUEST);die;
}
?>

<form action="index.php?a=12" method="get">
<input name="a" type="submit" value="Calc">
</form>
```

Output:

> array (size=1)   'a' => string 'Calc' (length=4)

Comment: You passed a such a hidden value, not just in url

Comment: What you want for output? If you want see only index.php after submit. You must use post method

Answer (score -1):

This method does not work because you put **a** not **sub** variable in URL, so I think you need to change to this :

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['a'])) {
    var_dump($_REQUEST);
    die;
}
?>
```

Try to do a `var_dump($_REQUEST);` before your if to see what you have.

Answer (score -1):

you have 2 options to send variables in the URL:

1. use a hyperlink

```
 <a href="index.php?a=12">Test!</a>
```

2. Use a form with GET, and have the field as hidden.

> ```
> <form action="index.php" method="get">
>     <input name="a" type="hidden" value="12">
>     <input name="sub" type="submit" value="Calc">
> </form>
> ```

You are mixing both methods, and the contents of the GET form, override your action.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, instead of:

```
if(isset($_GET['sub'])) {
```

use:

```
if(isset($_GET["sub"))}
```